# JSCEP with X509Certificate and Attribute Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, x509, jscep

I want to use `JSCEP` with Attribute Certificates (ACs), they are part of X.509. When I check the Java libraries. In the `java.security.cert` package a abstract `X509Certificate` is contained but this certificate inherits a `getPublicKey` method from `java.security.cert.Certificate`, which is not part of an AC.

My questions:

- Could the `X509Certificate` be used without a public key. So that no problems in the other java classes like `JcaX509CertificateConverter` appear?
- Should I implement a own `AttributeCertificate` class, which does not inherit from `java.security.cert.Certificate`?
- What would be the best practice approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X509Certificate` class represents a **Public Key Certificate** (PKC), while an **Attribute Certificate** (AC), although it's a similar (but not that much) structure, has no public key. And they're not the same thing.

A `X509Certificate` can't be used without a public key, because the key is part of it. If you take a look at the [RFC's definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1), you'll see it's a mandatory field:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }

TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    ... lots of fields...
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    ... }

SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The public key is also part of the definition of a PKC: something that binds an identity and a public key, as [stated in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-3.1):

> ...public key certificates, which are data structures that bind
> public key values to subjects

---

**Attribute Certificates** are defined in [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5755#section-1), which tells the differences from a PKC:

> Some people constantly confuse PKCs and ACs. An analogy may make
> the distinction clear.  A PKC can be considered to be like a
> passport: it identifies the holder, tends to last for a long time,
> and should not be trivial to obtain.  An AC is more like an entry
> visa: it is typically issued by a different authority and does not
> last for as long a time.  As acquiring an entry visa typically
> requires presenting a passport, getting a visa can be a simpler
> process.

In the same page, you can see that [AC's structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5755#section-4.1) is very different from a [PKC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1), so an AC's implementation shouldn't inherit from `X509Certificate`. Although there are some similar fields, I don't think they're close enough to justify inheritance (and they also have different purposes and uses, which makes me discard inheritance at all).

The best approach in your case: I'd recommend using an existing implementation. [BouncyCastle is one of them](http://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/AttributeCertificate.html). If you can't use an external lib, you can use [BouncyCastle's code](http://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) as a reference.

Comment: thank you very much for this good answer. Do you know if bouncycastle implements a protocol to manage ACs like the SCEP for PKCs?

Comment: Well, there's a `X509v2AttributeCertificateBuilder` class, I think you can use it (not sure if there's something more complete than that). I've found an example code [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/misc/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/examples/AttrCertExample.java)